# What to do to get into ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu

I had lubuntu 15.04 installed on my computer.
I wanted to switch to ubuntu. 
So i got into root mode using 'sudo su' and installed ubuntu using
apt-get installed ubuntu-desktop. After everything is over, I rebooted and it is booting into lubuntu. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Logout your current session

You should have the choice and select your display manager (click the little wheel) [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLEiZ.jpg)

Login

Comment: I got it. But the lock screen of lubuntu persists. How to remove that and switch to ubuntu lock screen?